# open a circleMarker's popup - leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, leaflet

Below mentioned function loads circleMarkers to leaflet map and binds popups to them. If I click on any one of these markers, it opens the popup; it works.

```
L.circleMarker([row.countryInfo.lat, row.countryInfo.long],
        {color:'red',opacity:0.3,weight:1, fillColor: 'red',fillOpacity:.3, radius: rad})
                    .bindPopup(`${row.country}<br>Cases: ${row.cases}<br>Recovered: ${row.recovered}<br>Deaths: ${row.deaths}`)
                    .addTo(map);
    });
```

Later in the script, I am using the below mentioned function to go to a specific lat long, when user chooses a country.

```
 map.flyTo([countryFound.countryInfo.lat, countryFound.countryInfo.long], 4);
```

Now, I want to open the same popup which I added earlier to the circleMarker.

Any way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your circlemarker to a var: `var circlemarker = L.circleMarker( ...`

And then call `circlemarker.openPopup()`